# tax_query showing no results

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries, tax-query

I'm creating a music database site with two custom post types: tracks and albums. I've linked the tracks to their respective albums with a custom taxonomy for the album's slug. On each album page, I'm trying to get a tracklist of the album by retrieving all tracks with a `dub_album_slug` taxonomy that matches the slug of the current album.
Here's my code for that query:

```
global $post;
$post_slug = $post->post_name;
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'dub_track',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'dub_album_slug',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => $post_slug,
        ),
        'orderby' => 'dub_track_no',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    ),
);
$tracks_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

At the moment, it doesn't output anything at all.  Even if I manually put in a term that I know exists and has posts associated with it, nothing happens.

Here's the code I use to output the data:

```
<?php if ($tracks_query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while ($tracks_query->have_posts()) : $tracks_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'dub_original_artist', '', ', ' ); ?>
etc.
```

Here's my custom post type registration:

```
//Register Track Custom Post Type
if ( ! function_exists('dub_track_custom_post_type') ) {

    // Register Custom Post Type
    function dub_track_custom_post_type() {

        $labels = array(
            'name'                => _x( 'Tracks', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
            'singular_name'       => _x( 'Track', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
            //...
        );
        $rewrite = array(
            'slug'                => 'track',
            'with_front'          => true,
            'pages'               => true,
            'feeds'               => false,
        );
        $args = array(
            'label'               => __( 'dub_track', 'text_domain' ),
            'description'         => __( 'Dub Tracks', 'text_domain' ),
            'labels'              => $labels,
            'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
            'taxonomies'          => array( 'track-no', 'original-artist', 'original-title', 'original-released', 'producer', 'comment', 'album-slug', 'artist', 'riddim' ),
            'hierarchical'        => false,
            'public'              => true,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_in_menu'        => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
            'menu_position'       => 5,
            'can_export'          => true,
            'has_archive'         => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
            'capability_type'     => 'post',
        );
        register_post_type( 'dub_track', $args );

    }

    // Hook into the 'init' action
    add_action( 'init', 'dub_track_custom_post_type', 0 );

}
```

Here's my custom taxonomy registration:

```
//Register Album Slug Custom Taxonomy
if ( ! function_exists( 'dub_album_slug' ) ) {

    // Register Custom Taxonomy
    function dub_album_slug() {

        $labels = array(
            'name'                       => _x( 'Album Slug', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
            'singular_name'              => _x( 'Album Slug', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
            //...
        );
        $rewrite = array(
            'slug'                       => 'album-slug',
            'with_front'                 => true,
            'hierarchical'               => false,
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels'                     => $labels,
            'hierarchical'               => false,
            'public'                     => true,
            'show_ui'                    => true,
            'show_admin_column'          => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
            'show_tagcloud'              => true,
            'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'dub_album_slug', array( 'dub_track' ), $args );

    }

    // Hook into the 'init' action
    add_action( 'init', 'dub_album_slug', 0 );

}
```

Here's what I get from `$tracks_query->request`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS dub_posts.ID FROM dub_posts INNER JOIN dub_term_relationships ON (dub_posts.ID = dub_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dub_term_relationships ON dub_posts.ID=dub_term_relationships.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dub_term_taxonomy USING (term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dub_terms USING (term_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( dub_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (16) ) AND dub_posts.post_type = 'dub_track' AND (dub_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (taxonomy = 'dub_track_no' OR taxonomy IS NULL) GROUP BY object_id ORDER BY GROUP_CONCAT(dub_terms.name ORDER BY name ASC) ASC LIMIT 0, 20
```

I'm not great with MySQL or how taxonomies work in the WordPress database.

I just thought of something that may be relevant.  I'm using some code I found to order the tracks by the track number taxonomy.  It modifies the MySQL query directly so I guess it could be causing a problem.  Here it is:

```
function orderby_tax_clauses( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
global $wpdb;
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies();
foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
    if ( isset( $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) && $taxonomy == $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) {
        $clauses['join'] .=<<<SQL
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID={$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} USING (term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)
SQL;
        $clauses['where'] .= " AND (taxonomy = '{$taxonomy}' OR taxonomy IS NULL)";
        $clauses['groupby'] = "object_id";
        $clauses['orderby'] = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.name ORDER BY name ASC) ";
        $clauses['orderby'] .= ( 'ASC' == strtoupper( $wp_query->get('order') ) ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
    }
}
return $clauses;
```

}

```
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'orderby_tax_clauses', 10, 2 );
```

I hope you can help me out.  Let me know if you need more code.
Cheers

Comment: what happens if you change `'field' => 'name'` to `'field' => 'slug'`?

Comment: That doesn't help I'm afraid.  Anyway, in this case, they're usually the same thing.

Comment: Have you checked if the actual taxonomy does exist? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/taxonomy_exists

Comment: `var_dump($tracks_query)` and check the query vars and generated SQL, should give you an idea of what's wrong.

Comment: How do you output the data? (the code givens doesn't display anything, it just stores the WP Query object in $tracks_query-variable.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Yes I've tried that just now and it definitely exists

Comment: @Milo I've done that but I'm not sure what to look for really.  There doesn't seem to be anything obvious though.  It appears to be looking for the right thing.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld `<?php if ($tracks_query->have_posts()) : ?>` `<?php while ($tracks_query->have_posts()) : $tracks_query->the_post(); ?>` `<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'dub_original_artist', '', ', ' ); ?>` etc.

Comment: @ubermatress - please put that code in your question instead. it's easiser to read :-)

Comment: `'album_slug' !== 'dub_album_slug'`

Comment: @PieterGoosen that was just a typo when posting the question - I've corrected it now

Comment: Please add the code that you've use to register the post type and taxonomies

Comment: Add the generated SQL query in $ tracks_query-> request, it should be apparent if its correct or not.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong there

Comment: Okay I've put up all the code that I think can possibly be relevant to the problem.  The order by track number code was working fine so I didn't add it earlier.

Comment: The dub_album_slug taxonomy is nowhere in your query, i'll guess its that post clauses filter breaking things. Remove it and see what the query looks like.

Comment: Well that seems to work now although I still can't see where it's filtering based on that taxonomy.  The problem is obviously with that code.  Thanks for finding where the problem lies.  It's important to order by track number though so I've still got a problem. Should I edit my question accordingly?  Sorry, I haven't done this before.

Comment: it's probably easier to order by meta data. save the track number in a custom field, then you can order on that meta key without having to do complex query manipulation.

Comment: Ideally, to avoid redoing a lot of work, I'd get it working this way but might it have been better to do all the track info as meta data using custom fields?

Comment: Never mind.  Having thought about it, leaving everything the same apart from swapping the track number to a custom field is the best solution.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@Milo found that the problem was with the code to order by the track number taxonomy.  I'm going to make track number a custom field.